# how to stop form submit if empty fields?

Tags: php, jquery, forms

my website is based off of only one `php` index file that changes the contents of the site based on the header variables. `www.mydomain.com/?page=contact` loads and brings up a form that i am having the user fill out.

i have some `jQuery` that **SHOULD** detect if there are any missing fields:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    var isFormValid = true;
    $(".required").each(function() {
        if ($.trim($(this).val()) == "") {
            $(this).addClass("highlight");
            isFormValid = false;
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("highlight");
        }
        if (!isFormValid) alert("Please fill in all the required fields (indicated by *)");
        return isFormValid;
    });
});
```

but it is not working....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put `return isFormValid` out of loop (**otherwise you are overwriting its value again and again**):

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    var isFormValid = true;
    $(".required").each(function() {
        if ($.trim($(this).val()) == "") {
            $(this).addClass("highlight");
            isFormValid = false;
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("highlight");
        }

    });

    if (!isFormValid) alert("Please fill in all the required fields (indicated by *)");
    return isFormValid; // put out of loop
});
```

Comment: actually can return it both places, returning it inside `each loop` will just cancel remainder of loop, but you are absolutely correct, has to be done outside for sure

Comment: @NoahPassalacqua: I have updated code, moved if condition below too

Comment: moved if condition out of loop `    if (!isFormValid) alert("Please fill in all the required fields (indicated by *)");
`

Comment: Also you also validating radio buttons and checkboxes ?

Comment: just one set of radio buttons. also moving the if condition out of the loop did not work :(

Comment: @NoahPassalacqua: You see `val()` doesn't work for radio buttons. Inside your loop you will have to check if looped element is radio button and use `is(':checked')` for it

Comment: ok thanks for that tip! but that cannot be the reason that it is not working

Comment: @NoahPassalacqua: Glad to know that, have fun :)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this?

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    var isFormValid = true;
    $(".required").each(function() {
        if ($.trim($(this).val()) == "") {
            $(this).addClass("highlight");
            isFormValid = false;
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("highlight");
        }
    });
    // the following lines should be placed here
    if (!isFormValid) {
        alert("Please fill in all the required fields (indicated by *)");
    }
    return isFormValid;
});
```

---

Or even shorter:

```
$("form").submit(function() {
    var isFormValid = $(".required").removeClass("highlight").filter(function() {
        return $.trim(this.value) == "";
    }).addClass("highlight").length == 0;

    if (!isFormValid) {
        alert("Please fill in all the required fields (indicated by *)");
    }
    return isFormValid;
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/YS6gw/

Answer (score 1):

```
Can you post the html works perfectly fine for me. 
Here is my Code :
------------------------

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript"  src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("form").submit(function() {
                var isFormValid = true;
                $(".required").each(function() {
                    if ($.trim($(this).val()) == "") {
                        $(this).addClass("highlight");
                        isFormValid = false;
                    } else {
                        $(this).removeClass("highlight");
                    }
                    if (!isFormValid) alert("Please fill in all the required fields (indicated by *)");
                    return isFormValid;
                });
            });

        });

    </script>

    <style type="text/css">
        #divMain {vertical-align: bottom;}
        .div1_style {background: #ffe4b5}
        .div2_style {background: #79b7e7}
        .highlight {background: #cd0a0a}
        .div_disabled_style {background: #6f6e73}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#" method="post">
<div id="divMain" align="center">
    <div id="div1" class="div2_style">
        <input type="checkbox" id="checkBox1">
        <input type="text" class ="required"  id="text1"/>
        <input type="text" class ="required" id="text2"/>
        <input type="text" class ="required" id="text3"/>
        <button type="submit" id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```